# Best practices for the input helper in new Ember components

Tags: javascript, ember.js, data-binding, handlebars.js

I'm currently learning about Ember's new data-down, actions-up paradigm for components. As discussed [here](http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/05/10/run-up-to-two-oh.html), however, sometimes I want to allow the child component to modify the property explicitly. This is where the *mut* helper comes in: it creates a wrapper for the passed in value, containing a (readonly?) value and a function to update it. The example on that page is for a simple button which increments a counter.

How does this concept work if I'm using the input helper inside a component? For example, let's say I'm building a form which consists of a bunch of special form components:

```
// templates/index.hbs
<form>
    {{form-control value=(mut model.firstValue)}}
    {{form-control value=(mut model.secondValue)}}
</form>
```

If the *form-control* component just has the task of wrapping the input control, how do we use the passed-in *mut* object correctly? Is it something like?

```
// templates/components/form-control.hbs
{{input type="text" value=attrs.value.value input=attrs.value.update}}
```

My thinking here: the value of the input element is set to the value of the *mut* object, and whenever the input value changes (HTML5 input event) the update method of the *mut* object is called to set the model property to the new value. It seems there's something wrong with my thinking though, because this doesn't work. What is the "standard" way of doing this now? I'm using Ember 1.13.8.

Comment: Here's a  good [article](http://emberup.co/bindings-with-htmlbars-helpers/?utm_source=Ember+Weekly&utm_campaign=d59b972512-Ember_Weekly_Issue_125&utm_medium=email&utm_term=0_e96229d21d-d59b972512-106355381) talking about  the mutable and read only helpers. Hopefully that'll help out

Comment: Thanks Tyler, really appreciate it. Unfortunately it hasn't helped me all that much though. It shows the view from the consumer, i.e. how to create a readonly version of the value and an action to update, both of which are passed to the component. Unless I misunderstand something, this is what the mut helper does too (i.e. it creates a readonly version of the value and an action to update it). Where I get lost is on the component side when I want to use those two ingredients in an input helper...how do I bind the readonly value to the input, and call the update method when the input changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In classic components (as opposed to glimmer components), all bindings are mutable, so it is not generally necessary to use the `mut` helper. The following should work fine:

```
// templates/index.hbs
<form>
  {{form-control value=model.firstValue}}
  {{form-control value=model.secondValue}}
</form>

// templates/components/form-control.hbs
{{input type="text" value=value}}
```

The intended use of both the `mut` helper and of `attrs` is for glimmer components, also called angle bracket components, which are currently not released in Ember.js' stable releases.